# can anyone guid me to plot the image in latex using tikz. i have shared the image file

Tags: latex, tikz, pgfplots

[I want to draw this image in a latex file using tikz and pgfplots. I have no idea I to do it. i just need the exact image shown in the image file in latex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpClr.png)

Comment: Have a look at section "2 Tutorial: A Picture for Karl’s Students" from the TikZ user guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below produces this:

[the output figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QMEH.png)

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,bm}\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, angles, quotes} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, x=6mm, y=6mm, thick]
    \draw (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[right] {$\boldsymbol{x}$};
    \draw (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5) node[above] {$\boldsymbol{y}$};
    \draw (5,0.1) -- (5,-0.1) node[below] {$\boldsymbol{5}$};
    \draw (0.1,5) -- (-0.1,5) node[left] {$\boldsymbol{5}$};
    \draw (-5,0.1) -- (-5,-0.1) node[below] {$\boldsymbol{5}$};
    \draw (0.1,-5) -- (-0.1,-5) node[left] {$\boldsymbol{5}$};
    \draw[-{Stealth[length=3mm]}] (0,0) -- (4,-3);
    \node[below] at (2,-1.5) {$\mathbf{A}$};
    \draw[dotted] (4,0) -- (4,-3);
    \draw[dotted] (0,-3) -- (4,-3);
    \node[right] at (4,-2) {$\boldsymbol{-3}$};
    \node[below] at (2,-3) {$\boldsymbol{4}$};
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0); \coordinate (b) at (1,0); \coordinate (c) at (2,-1.5);
    \draw pic[draw, angle radius=0.8cm, "$\boldsymbol{\alpha}$" shift={(0.2,-0.1)}] {angle=c--a--b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you bro for giving this code